# Displayport over USB-C stopped working - faulty drivers?

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, external-monitor, displayport

My laptop (Dell XPS 13, 9350) has a single USB-C port, which I am used to connecting to a docking station which is in turn connected to peripherals (USB devices, audio, display, power supply). One day when booting up the computer, the display had stopped working: the laptop still 'sees' that an external monitor is connected, but the monitor reports that it receives no signal.

Since monitor and docking station were working fine, I feared the worst: a broken USB-C port. But when I booted my laptop from a live USB with Ubuntu, suddenly the external monitor was working. So the issue must be driver related. The problem started a few weeks ago and I honestly did not expect this issue to be driver related, so I am afraid I cannot reconstuct which changes were made to the software shortly before the issue started occurring.

In summary: Dell XPS 13 9350, Ubuntu 20.04.3, 64bit, kernel 5.11.0-27-generic, integrated Intel HD Graphics 520. USB-C port still works for power supply and to connect USB and audio devices, but no longer properly sends the Displayport signal.

**Update:** Based on the following log entry

```
i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Link Training Unsuccessful
```

I found the following related [bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1903969). Supposedly, the problem should be solved in kernel version 5.11.

Curiously, I found that booting in the old kernel 5.4.0-81-generic instead resolved the issue. I would rather not downgrade so many kernel versions, and my technical knowledge is too limited to read from the discussion on the Launchpad bug report what to do to patch the problem manually.

Comment: I have a DELL XPS 13, 9300 and I'm getting similar issues. What did you do?

Comment: @Jonathan As in the answer below, I reverted to an older kernel version (5.4) whilst waiting for the bug to be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug as recorded here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.11/+bug/1939297.

It is still present in kernel 5.11.0-34-generic as I experienced today (on Lenovo T14 Gen1 with ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock Gen 2 and monitor connected via DisplayPort). If I switch to kernel 5.8.0-63 the problem is gone.

**Update (2021-09-28)**:

The issue is fixed for me with kernel 5.11.0-37-generic #41 that arrived for Ubuntu 20.04.2 today.

Comment: So for now... you only have to run away from it, making this a workaround and not really a solution, right?

Comment: @ThunderBird, you are right. Should I better delete the answer? I had the feeling I could still add valuable information for the OP that I could not add by other means (no comments allowed yet). Anyway, still learning... ;) What would have been the right way?

Comment: Thanks @dr_eja, indeed I also ended up reverting to kernel 5.4, resolving the issue. I would say that the purpose of this website is to help users get their devices working, not to patch kernel bugs, so I am certainly willing to accept this as a solution until the developers patch the problem.